# What is the easiest way to display a JPG using wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

All the examples I've seen seem very complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: GUI programming is complicated by its very nature. The easiest way to display a JPG is to use an existing program instead of trying to write your own.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what command to use.  So far I have code to display a black square inside a frame and text inside the black square, but that's semi-unrelated: http://pastebin.com/t75gkGN8 I couldn't find a command to add an image to a window.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess I will try to copy theirs then, I just don't understand it very well.

Comment: That's often how it works, yeah.  Just bundle the relevant code into a well-named function like `showJPG(pic)` and you're off and running.  Unless you need to start tweaking it, you don't reeeaaally need to know how it works.  That is the magic of a well-written API, if you can get one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wx demo has an image example, under Using Images|Image.  It shows how to convert and display a jpg, and other types as well.  If you don't already have the demo, you can get it from the main wx download page.